# Iterating with size_t 0 as a boundary condition

Tags: c++, c

What's the "correct" way to write a decreasing loop with a size_t value and a boundary condition. Example incorrect implementation:

```
for (size_t elemNum = listSize-1; elemNum >= 0; --elemNum) { /* ... */ }
```

When it reaches zero it will wrap around to the max value rather than acting as a boundary condition. Iterating the loop in reverse is necessary. It seems like a problem that would have a defacto standard solution but I can't find what it is.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The most succinct approach is to use post-increment:

```
for (size_t i = listSize; i--;) ...
```

Comment: umm, this won't behave any different to --i?

Comment: oh, I see, the increment is in the condition. My bad

Comment: I think it works, but imo using a while loop like pmg suggested is easier to understand than "misusing" for in that way.

Comment: @Medo42: How is the while-loop approach any less of a "misuse"? Plus, it broadens the scope of the loop variable beyond the loop, which is bad karma.

Comment: I like this solution the best. So long as the "goes to" operator mentioned in the other comment is understood I can make it even more clear as:
`for (size_t i = listSize; i --> 0;) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: @Stravant: That's quite ingenious! I don't know if it's clearer, though. You'll have people reaching for their text books trying to figure out what the `-->` operator does.

Comment: @MarkLangen: except that `i` is an unsigned type and the `> 0` check misleads readers/maintainers into thinking `i` could ever be negative. By omitting the relational operator the implicit `!= 0` in this answer avoids that.

Answer (score 7):

```
elemNum = listsize;
while (elemNum--) {
    /* work with elemNum varying from `listsize - 1` down to `0` */
}
```

Comment: Some compilers support the special "goes to" operator, `while (elemNum --> 0) { /* ... */ }` for this purpose.

Comment: @Kerrek: I think you mean all Standard conforming compilers :)

Comment: @pmg, a small nitpick here: the `elemNum` will not be 0 after this (there will be a wrap-around just after the last iteration). Since the asker's `for` loop didn't even make `elemNum` visible outside of the loop it probably does not matter, but it is (very slightly) cleaner to do the decrement as first line inside the loop.

Comment: @Branko I don't think that is a small nitpick, but a real counter argument. Local index variables in `for` loops do have a reasons, and so this answer here is not appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a standard way, but this should work:

```
for (size_t elemNum = listSize-1; elemNum < listSize; --elemNum) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: That's a pretty neat way of doing it.

Comment: no, it's a pretty obfuscated way. it's so ugly I would like to downvote it.. :/

Comment: Well, I don't see it tricky at all. I see it very elegant and intelligent.

Comment: I think pmg's solution is the best so far, and would recommend it over mine.

Comment: This approach is fragile. The type of the loop variable might change later (e.g., a maintenance programmer might do so to resolve type comparison warnings, and may neglect to properly inspect the code), and then all bets are off.

Comment: @Medo42 This will work because `size_t` is actually guaranteed to be unsigned. However, this is not a good approach in general - the type of the index may not even be known in advance, such as inside a template.

Comment: @Daniel: Why would that be the case?  When `elemNum` wraps around, it would be equal to `SIZE_MAX`, and `elemNum < listSize` would be false since they would be equal values.

Answer (score 2):

You could use two variables instead:

```
size_t count = 0;
for (size_t elemNum = listSize-1; count < listSize; ++count, --elemNum) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (size_t counter = listSize; counter > 0; --counter) { 
     size_t index = counter-1;

    /* ... use `index` as an index ... */ 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
size_t elemNum = listSize;
while (elemNum > 0) {
    --elemNum;
    // Do your work here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this as the condition:

```
elemNum != (size_t)-1
```

Or you could count up, and do some math (which the compiler will probably optimise out anyway) for your index:

```
for (size_t i = 1; i <= listSize; i++) {size_t elemNum = listSize-i; /* */}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can *guarantee* the starting value isn’t too large, a simple answer is: use a signed type instead.

Answer (score -1):

The standard C++ way would be to use a [`std::reverse_iterator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x256702%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Somehow within the loop you are accessing element `elemNum` of a list, say via `list[elemNum]`, where `list` models the RandomAccessIterator concept. Suppose that `list_iterator_type` is the decltype of `list`. Your loop using reverse iterators becomes:

```
std::reverse_iterator<list_iterator_type> it, end = std::reverse_iterator<list_iterator_type>(list);
for (it = std::reverse_iterator<list_iterator_type>(list + listSize); it != end; ++it) {
    // `*it` is `list[elemNum]`
}
```